# Trigger can created on UserServicePresence while Salesforce doc says it is not supported. Can we package the trigger as well?

Tags: trigger, omnichannel, packaging

Trigger on UserServicePresence object can be created after we enable omnichannel. Can we package this trigger? As target org can be having omnichannel settings disabled.

Salesforce doc says trigger is not supported on this object https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userservicepresence.htm

Answer (score 2):

I have faced with similar issue in my omnichannel implementations and found triggers on this object can be created but they do not fire, or at least shows up in apex debug logs.

Comment: Is there any workaround to capture status change of User??

Comment: I was able to create, deploy and run a trigger on the UserServicePresence SObject (Winter '21)

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I got this to work in Flows with a record triggered flow and on create and on update changes. This is on Spring '22 in a sandbox environment.

We basically wanted a Slack message to be sent to a channel on an OmniChannel user status change. That would help the support managers know what is happening all day and save a step for the support engineers having to say "in queue" or "out of queue" and switching their status inside of OmniChannel.